# Do Android One tablets exist?

Tags: stock-android, android-one

I am looking for the zero bloat, 100% pure [Android One](https://www.android.com/one/) experience.

So far, I have only been able to find phones with Android One, like the Xiaomi Mi A2.

Do Android One tablets exist? Or if not, are there resellers of rooted hardware with reflashed ROM with stock Android?

Comment: Android One devices aren't bloat-free. Vendors are bound to ship their devices with Google apps, the most organized and beutified form of bloatware. Android One is targeted to streamline OTA updates for LTS, not to keep devices bloat-free.

Comment: Have you considered finding a model that is supported by LineageOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page on Android One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_One) has a complete list of all Android One devices released, and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any tablets.
There couldn't be any tablet resellers with Android One (the source code is not available, and it is impossible to port from phones to tablets) and there's none I'm aware of selling stock Android either.
If you don't mind the warranty and willing to do some tweaking (it's almost always worth it) you can flash a stock AOSP ROM yourself, as there's no risk for **most** devices (some are risky) [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) for your device should have ROMs, flashing guides and guides on how to recover your device if something goes wrong. It could be good to check there if these are present there before buying a device.
Good luck!